# Golang copy all values of context

Tags: go, go-context

I have a HTTP server application which serves async jobs.

```
-> Request
   --> Do async job with goroutine
<- Response
    -------start goroutine------
       -> Job1
          -> Job1A
          -> Job1B
       -> Job2
       -> Job3
```

User can request for the long running async job and the application responses to the request immediately after make goroutine.

I put Request ID, authenticated token, and user information in `context.Context` of the request. And, I want to bring it under the goroutines. But, using the same `context` with the request `context` will cause unexpected cancel after the response, which is not my intended behavior.

How can I generate new `context` with all values, independent from the parent request `context`? Or, any other way to guarantee the `context` bring into the goroutines is not dead after response?

One more extra question:

`Job1` ~ `Job3` should be serialized, i.e., `Job2` should wait for `Job1` and `Job3` wait for `Job2`. And, `Job1A` and `Job1B` can be run simultaneously. If I want to propagate cancelation of given `context`, how can I make cancel path(?) of them? Should I check with select statement of all functions?

I understood concepts of `context` propagating cancelation and early exit without doing meaningless tasks. However, I didn't catch how to deal within the code yet. I'll be happy if someone can help understanding.

Comment: @CharlieTumahai Yes, you're right. I'm asking for dealing with the situation when the `context` cancelled.

Comment: You can stop the propagation of the cancelation with [context.WithoutCancel](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithoutCancel).

Comment: @Peter Thanks! That's what I was looking for. Then I can keep all values without interference of parent cancelation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to discover the values in a context. They are not stored as a map, they are stored as layers of contexts, and each level may provide a different implementation of how values are stored.

However, if you know what values you need to propagate, you can query them and create a new context using those values.

That said, you can implement a new context type that uses the values in another context:

```
type newContext struct {
  context.Context
  values context.Context
}

func (c newContext) Value(key any) any {
  return c.values.Value(key)
}

...
newCtx:=newContext{
  Context: context.Background(),
  values: ctx,
}
```

This uses an existing context for values and a new context for everything else.

Then, start a new goroutine to continue processing the request using that new context.

If you want to create multiple concurrent jobs, you can do that in that goroutine:

```
go func(ctx context.Context) {
   withCancel, cancel:=context.WithCancel(ctx)
   defer cancel()

   wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
   wg.Add(2)
   go job1(withCancel,&wg)
   go job2(withCancel,&wg)
   wg.Wait()
}(newCtx)
```

This way, when the context is canceled, both jobs will get the cancellation notification. If you want to control cancellation of job1 and job2 separately:

```
go func(ctx context.Context) {
   withCancel1, cancel1:=context.WithCancel(ctx)
   defer cancel1()
   withCancel2, cancel2:=context.WithCancel(ctx)
   defer cancel2()

   wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
   wg.Add(2)
   go job1(withCancel1,&wg)
   go job2(withCancel2,&wg)
   wg.Wait()
}(newCtx)
```

For sequential jobs (i.e. job3 finishes after job1), simply combine them so they appear like a single job.

To check if a context is canceled, you can do a `select` on the `Done` channel of the context, or simply check:

```
if ctx.Err()!=nil {
   // Context canceled
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then, to check a given `context` is canceled path under the parent, do I need to add `if ctx.Err() ! =nil { return ctx.Err() }` to all function paths?

Comment: Correct. The error value will tell if it timed out or canceled